# Wordpress: get_post_gallery image custom size

Tags: wordpress, post, gallery

I'm trying to display the post gallery manually, however images are resized to the default thumbnail size, which is way too small. I'm developing a theme which I'd like to sell in the future, so I would like to display the images from the gallery at a custom size, ignoring wordpress settings. How can I do that?

Here's my code:

```
if ( get_post_gallery() ) :
    $gallery = get_post_gallery( get_the_ID(), false );
    foreach( $gallery['src'] AS $src )
    {
        ?>
        <li data-thumb="<?php echo $src; ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo $src; ?>" alt="Gallery image" />
        </li>
        <?php
    }
endif;
```

I already specified my preffered size in my functions.php file like this: `add_image_size( 'slider-size', 1200, 680 );`.

So how can I display gallery images manually in a specific size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a filter to act on `shortcode_atts_gallery` before you call that gallery ...

```
add_filter('shortcode_atts_gallery','force_large_images',10,3);
function force_large_images($out, $pairs, $atts) {
  $out['size'] = 'my_size'; // for example, "large" 
  return $out;
}
```

do not forget also to remove that filter if you do not want it any more ..

```
remove_filter('shortcode_atts_gallery','force_large_images',10,3);
```

another way would be to perform your own query ...

```
    $args = array( 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_parent' => $post->ID, 'order' => 'ASC');
    $attachments = get_children($args);

    foreach( $attachments as $attachment) { 
        if ( !empty($attachment->guid ) ) {
            $img_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment->ID, 'full'); //change *full* size with your custom size

// and then do something ..
}
```

Comment: Uh, I've just noticed something. If i have more than one image in the gallery, the code above works only for the first image. The second one doesn't get the custom size I want (1144x680). What's wrong?

Comment: By the way, I'm using the last method you posted.